# Responsive Javascript not working on one of the pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just implented a responsive design for www.star-registration.com.
It seems to work fine on most of the browsers but on some the startpage www.star-registration.com isn't working but www.star-registration.com/order/ and all other pages work fine.
The problem occurs when I use firefox and resize the browser. I quess it's because of the Javascript files http://www.star-registration.com/skin/frontend/default/sterntaufeeUSA/js/responsive_slider/responsive_slider.js and http://www.star-registration.com/skin/frontend/default/sterntaufeeUSA/js/jquery.slicknav.js

any suggestions why the startpage isn't getting displayed properly?

Comment: is URL of the site really nesessary for community to answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed because you use JS. The JS checks the width of the screen only once (as far as I see at least), so when the page loads it aplies the different styles, but not when resizing.

I would suggest CSS Media Queries instead.
[Check the W3Schools Instructions](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)